# Getting listItem data from a list

Tags: java, android, listview

I hate a list created by simple cursor adapter:

```
Cursor c = myDbHelper.rawQ(select);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { "Books.BookTitle",
            "Publishers.Publisher" };
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ISBN_entry, R.id.Title_entry };

    // Getting results into our listview
    try {
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listlayout, c, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

The layout involved with the list are two simple textviews.

What i want to do is create a listener

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

The part im failing at is retrieving the BookTitle part of the specific entry(row) in order to requery the database and present the data with AlertDialog.Builder.

When i try doing :

```
 String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

i'm only getting android.database.sqlite SQLiteCursor@44f99e80 and im rather confused on how this should be done (I know why it's crashign just can;t get my mind around on how it should be done properly.

Full code atm:

```
...
Cursor c = myDbHelper.rawQ(select);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { "Books.BookTitle",
            "Publishers.Publisher" };
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ISBN_entry, R.id.Title_entry };

    // Getting results into our listview
    try {
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listlayout, c, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }



}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  
 new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
 .setTitle("Title")
 .setMessage(selection)
 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
 .show();
} }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
Cursor theCursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)((ListView)l).getAdapter()).getCursor();
String selection = theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex("Books.BookTitle"));
```

Comment: @GGe: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the data from the cursor:

```
 l.getItemAtPosition(position).getString(0); // it might be 1
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).